# Dynamic field names in Django Mixin

Tags: django, mixins, django-class-based-views

I have these class based ListView's which I would like to filter by date. I have a simple mixin
to display the filterform, which works great:

```
class MonthYearFormMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MonthYearFormMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['monthyearform'] = MonthYearForm(self.request.GET)
        return context
```

I would like to extend the functionality of this mixin to include the queryset filtering, but my models 
have different date fields that need to be filtered on, one might be start_date, another might be 
invoice_date. Of course someone might say, "rename them all 'date'", but that's not representative 
of my models and furthermore, I might have a model with start_date and end_date, but only want to filter 
on start_date. Here are my views:

```
class SentList(MonthYearFormMixin, ListView):
    model = Sent
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'sent_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        if 'month' in self.request.GET:
            if int(self.request.GET['month']) > 0:
                qs = qs.filter(start_date__month=self.request.GET['month'])
        if 'year' in self.request.GET:
            if int(self.request.GET['year']) > 0:
                qs = qs.filter(start_date__year=self.request.GET['year'])
        return qs

class ReceivedList(MonthYearFormMixin, ListView):
    model = Received
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'received_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        if 'month' in self.request.GET:
            if int(self.request.GET['month']) > 0:
                qs = qs.filter(invoice_date__month=self.request.GET['month'])
        if 'year' in self.request.GET:
            if int(self.request.GET['year']) > 0:
                qs = qs.filter(invoice_date__year=self.request.GET['year'])
        return qs
```

The only thing that's different is the name of the date field, so it's frustrating to have to repeat 
this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a member variable called `date_field_name` where you store the name of the field names which should be processed by your QuerySet processor mixin?

This list would be defined in the class which uses the mixin.

Something like

```
class MonthYearFormMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MonthYearFormMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['monthyearform'] = MonthYearForm(self.request.GET)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        if 'month' in self.request.GET:
            if int(self.request.GET['month']) > 0:
                kwargs = {('%s__month' % self.date_field_name): self.request.GET['month']}
                qs = qs.filter(**kwargs)
        if 'year' in self.request.GET:
            if int(self.request.GET['year']) > 0:
                kwargs = {('%s__year' % self.date_field_name): self.request.GET['year']}
                qs = qs.filter(**kwargs)
    return qs
```

your views would look like this:

```
class SentList(MonthYearFormMixin, ListView):
    model = Sent
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'sent_list.html'
    date_field_name = 'start_date'
```

Comment: qs = qs.filter(start_date__month=self.request.GET[date_field_name]) -> start_date is the field name that needs to be dynamic in the filtering. What if the field name was invoice_date?

Comment: Just refreshed and saw your edit, will test it out along with another idea I just had...

Comment: Correct "your forms would look like this:" to read "your views would look like this:" and it works perfectly. I never thought to pass kwargs to filter like that. Excellent!